# DialogFragment not displaying message

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("This is a title");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("This is a message");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", null);

        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        // Do something
    }

    public void showAllowingStateLoss(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(this, "MyDialogFragment");
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
dialog.showAllowingStateLoss(fragmentManager);
```

The problem is that the message isn't shown in the app, it just displays this:

[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using dialog fragment when you use AlertDialog inside ?

Comment: @JozefDochan don't know, this is a simplified version of code from an app that I have "inherited" :) I know very little about Android development, I'm just trying to fix a bug.

Comment: theres no point for using dialogFragment if you want to show some message and yes/no buttons. Simply where are you creating dialogFragment create AlerDialog

Comment: Tried it, it gives the same result, the message isn't displayed. I',m starting to think that the message is displayed, but with white text on white background. Don't understand why though, there is no "android:alertDialogTheme".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Apparently the dialog use `android:textColorPrimary` from the theme as the text-color, and that color is white in my app. That results in an alertdialog that contains white text on a white background.

The solution was thus to add this in theme.xml:

```
<style name="MyAndroidTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/MyAlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyAlertDialogTheme" parent="MyAndroidTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

I don't really know why `android:windowIsFloating` is needed, but without it, the dialog becomes fullscreen.

Answer (score 3):

No need to add `DialogFragment.` We have `show()` method for showing the dialog. May be the issue is this.

```
MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(),dialog.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This results in the exact same behavior as the code in my question - a dialog-box with no text, only a title and buttons :(